# Dynamically change textview content in android

Tags: text, time, textview

I have a text view to which a variable is set. This variable changes with time. I want that the text of this textview also changes automatically. How should I do that? Is it possible to add something like a timer and as it tics, the text will be updated?

Answer (score 1):

use this inside OnClick(), if you want to add when button click...

```
LinearLayout child_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
child_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
TextView subject_name = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
textview.setText("add_new_text");
child_layout.addView(textview);
```

or

```
String text = "your_text";
textview.setText(text);
```